# How transfer uv to object that has been sculpt with dyntopo?

Tags: uv

I have a cube and duplicate it. I keep the original cube as source/master and sculpt the duplicated cube with dyntopo. Is it possible to transfer the uv layout back to the duplicated one ? I tried the 'transfer uv' function in blender but it's not working.

Comment: You might be able to bake the texture some how like you would a normal...

Comment: There is no way.